# Mathematical formulation for equation in a loop

Tags: functions

How can somebody write in a mathematical framework for a recursively defined function, for example:

$ f = f(t,x,g(t,x)) $ and $ g = g(t,x) $

```
for i = 1:t_end
```

$ f^{(i)} = \alpha \cdot f^{(i-1)} + \beta \cdot g^{(i)} $ 
where, $ g^{(i)} = \int_{i-1}^{i} g \cdot dt $

```
end
```

Comment: What is $g^i$ ?

Comment: $g^i$ is also a function.

Comment: For which the same recurrance relation holds ?

Comment: yes, indeed the index $i$ is for both $f$ and $g$ functions.

Comment: Can you maybe add the definition of $g^i$?

Comment: i updated the original post, hope it helps.

Comment: You give a way to compute $f^i=\alpha...$ but not for $g^i$, that is what would help.

Comment: i updated again the post.

Comment: Note that you cannot always find a closed form expression for a recursively defined function (i.e. for a "function inside a loop"), even though it is possible in the specific example you give.

Comment: Also, note that it is better to avoid using superscripts when indexing functions or numbers, because it can be easily confused with exponentiation. Alternative notations could be $f_i$ or $f^{(i)}$.

Comment: thanks @A.P. for your suggestions, i altered my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the indices, but it should turn out to be something like

\begin{align}
f_i &= \alpha f_{i-1} + \beta g_i = \alpha ( \alpha f_{i-2}+\beta g_{i-1})+\beta g_i = ...\\
&=
\alpha^i f_0 +\beta \sum_{k=1}^i \alpha^{i-k} g_k.
\end{align}

Now to evaluate $f_{t_{end}}$, just use $i=t_{end}$ in the above formula, that is
\begin{align}
f_{t_{end}} &= 
\alpha^{t_{end}} f_0 +\beta \sum_{k=1}^{t_{end}} \alpha^{t_{end}-k} g_k.
\end{align}

Comment: The 2nd right-hand term is correct. For the first one I doubt. Actually I am looking an expression where my left hand side I want to be just $f^{t_{end}} = .. $ and the evaluation at $t_end$ should include the influence from all previous steps. If it can be written in one expression..

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for the confusing notation with the indices. Of course for $g$ and $f$ the superscript denotes the $i$th or $k$th $f$ and $g$, respectively. For $\alpha$, the superscript denotes the power. I will edit the answer and replace the superscripts for $f$ and $g$ by subscripts.

Comment: ok @sonystarmap the edited answer should do the job.